# How to catch exceptions like x64dbg does?

Tags: c#, windbg, ocx, .net-4.6, heap-corruption

I'm developing an application with C#.NET 4.6
It references an old OCX LAPI.ocx

When this OCX receives some special message called PCPCM entire application crashes with HEAP Corruption exception.

Unfortunately I can't catch or handle that exception in my application.
Yesterday I tried my application with x32dbg. And it worked. x32dbg can catch exceptions and ignores them. How it can ignore such an exception? How I can do this in my application to prevent a crash?

**UPDATE:** I used dbg to find the point that the ocx raises an exception and tried to jump over it(and patched the original ocx). I put it under test. Hope it works.

**UPDATE 2:** I couldn't find a way to ignore or catch such exceptions. I couldn't make AddVectoredExceptionHandler working. But downgrading application to .NET 4.0 solved the original problem(No more exception and application crashed message).

Comment: Ignoring _heap corruption_ seems to be not good idea anyway?

Comment: AddVectoredExceptionHandler? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679274(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @arrowd above comment is really question to you, not to me.

Comment: @Evk sorry, it was a mistake.

Comment: @arrowd, would you please explain more about this VectoredHandler? How should I use it in my code(Which is a managed code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .NET 4.0 I solved the problem entirely. See UPDATE 2.